# Selenium Doesn't Found Login fields

Tags: selenium

I need your help in order to locate my login IDs/pass on this html table/form.As per the documentation i tried to locate the id and pass as:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_name('login_id')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('login_pwd')
```

The XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="login_id"]
//*[@id="login_pwd"]
```

I used until now:

```
<input style="width:140px" type="text" name="login_id" id="login_id" onchange="ResetRetryAttempts()">
element = driver.find_element_by_id("login_id")
element.clear()
element.send_keys("yuhuuu")


<input style="width:140px" type="password" name="login_pwd" id="login_pwd">
element = driver.find_element_by_id("login_pwd")
element.clear()
element.send_keys("xxxxx")

<input type="submit" name="button" value="OK">
element =driver.find_element_by_name('button')
element.click
element.submit()
```

The fact that the id and pass are into a table/form make the module not to see the id and pass field. Please can you help me with this? Thank you!

```
> <form autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return login();"> <table id="outerTable" style="width:100%">       <tbody><tr>         <td class="page_title" align="middle"   </tr>

                            <span name="form1" action="" target="_top" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to">


                                <table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td class="login" align="right">User</td>
                                    <td align="right"><input style="width:140px" type="text" name="login_id" id="login_id" onchange="ResetRetryAttempts()"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="login" align="right">Password</td>
                            <td align="right"><input style="width:140px" type="password" name="login_pwd" id="login_pwd"></td>


                                    <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="button" value="OK"></td>
```

Comment: is the whole table is inside any frame/iframe?

Comment: Hi Santosh!Thanks for your answer! I don't think so. the first row from the HTML code shows a <form. I think that the login code is within a table, cos the normal code is not working.

Comment: From the link, it is clear that the table/form is inside a frame. Switch to that frame and then try

Comment: thanks Madhan! How i can do that? thank you!

Comment: i found out the missing piece: browser.switch_to_frame("main"). However i require help with the click on the OK/Login Button. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the other newbies like me:

1. you will have to move to the frame that has the correct login details. For me it worked:

> browser.switch_to_frame(NAMEOFTHEFRAME)

2. if you end up to the login button and the driver can't click on the button, i did the

> element.send_keys(Keys.Space)

. So instead of doing click simply use the key space and this did the trick!
PS pls tell me how i can mark the naswer as solved. Thank you!